# Regular Expression (regex) Pattern Matching in Python

Tags: python, regex

My regular expression in python is as follows:

```
\\newcommand\\shortpage[.*?][.*?]{.*?{.*?}}
```

The text I am trying to match is:

```
\newcommand\shortpage[1][1]{\enlargethispage*{-#1\baselineskip}} % see Latex Companion, 2nd ed., p. 234
```

How do I fix my regular expression so that it properly matches my text?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Brackets and braces are metacharacters, you need to escape them:

```
\\newcommand\\shortpage\[.*?\]\[.*?\]\{.*?\{.*?\}\}
```

Actually, many regex engines don't require you to escape braces if it can be inferred from context that they aren't used as quantifiers (as in `x{2,4}`), but it's better to be explicit.

Furthermore, `.*` and `.*?` should be replaced, if possible, with something more specific than "match anything":

```
\\newcommand\\shortpage\[[^\]]*\]\[[^\]]*\]\{[^}]*\{[^}]*\}\}
```